# Notify <2k rep users about rejected edits

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

When I had <2k rep, I frequently made suggested edits to posts that needed it when the Suggested Edits queue wasn't full. During that time, I would receive a notification when one of my edits was approved, but nothing when one was rejected.

Since I reached 2k rep, I have been going through the Suggested Edits queue. Seeing others' edits now makes me think that low-rep users would benefit from getting notifications about their rejected suggested edits and the reject reasons. I don't see any reason for giving reject reasons if the users who made the edit can't get feedback on their edits. Just even an inbox message in the format of this would work:

> Your suggested edit on [TITLE_OF_QUESTION](LINK_TO_SUGGEST_EDIT) has been rejected.

Can/should this be added?